# Forming range query involving integers in Lucene

Tags: lucene

I am searching for documents in Lucene index whose **start time** field value is less than or equal to my time (t) and **finish time** field value is greater than my time(t). Here start time, finish time and my time all are in **hh:mm** format. I have converted all of them to a integral value that is equal to **hh*60+mm**.
Now I want to check whether value of my time lies in the range between the value associated with start time and value associated with finish time.

But here I have encountered several problems. they are as follows:

1.I cannot add fields with integral values to an index.

2.I cannot understand how to form this range query in Lucene involving integers.

So if anyone helps me to solve this I will be grateful Thank you.

Answer (score 0):

1:  Use [IntField](http://lucene.apache.org/core/4_0_0/core/org/apache/lucene/document/IntField.html), for instance:

```
document.add(new IntField("starttime", 1234, Field.Store.YES));
```

2:  [The query parser now supports Numeric Range queries](https://issues.apache.org/jira/browse/LUCENE-1768), simply like `starttime:[1234 TO 1345]`, or you can create a [NumericRangeQuery](http://lucene.apache.org/core/4_0_0/core/org/apache/lucene/search/NumericRangeQuery.html) yourself, like:

```
Query rangeQuery = NumericRangeQuery.newIntRange("starttime", 1234, 1345, false, false);
```

Or for a greater than, a range can be open by passing a null for one of the values.

```
Query rangeQuery = NumericRangeQuery.newIntRange("starttime", 1234, null, false, false);
```

Comment: Sir I cannot use IntField with my Lucene i.e. Lucene 3.6.2. Is not it supported for all versions of Lucene?

Comment: No, the typed class Numerics came in with Lucene 4.0.  You want [NumericField](http://lucene.apache.org/core/3_6_0/api/all/org/apache/lucene/document/NumericField.html#setIntValue(int)).  Support for Numeric range querying in the queryparser came in with Lucene 3.4, if I understand, so you should be fine on that, and the NumericRangeQuery API hasn't changed too very much.

Comment: Thank you, Sir :) I have downloaded Lucene 4.3.0 and now I am using that version.

Comment: If you are just getting started with Lucene, I think moving to 4.x is prudent.  If you already have a significant codebase using 3.x, the [migration guide](http://lucene.apache.org/core/4_0_0-ALPHA/MIGRATE.html) may be helpful to you.

Comment: Yes Sir I am a beginner in Lucene. I do not require much change in my code in order to incorporate Lucene 4.3.0. I have already done it. Thank you, Sir :)